# Django, how to get current request method? request is not working in my views.py

Tags: django, python-requests

I'm new to Django. I'm trying to get my current request method to see if it is "POST" method.

But I got error message says: Unresolved reference 'request'

I tried to import request, but I don't know which one is correct.

[import choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYiMP.png)

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,

Xi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following:

```
    import requests
    response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
```